# babelify transform not running

Tags: node.js, browserify, babeljs, tsify

I'm having trouble getting babelify to run on my code.

I've got two typescript files:

script1.ts

```
import Greeter from './script2';

const greeter = new Greeter('Hello, world!');

document.body.innerHTML = greeter.greet();
```

script2.ts

```
class Greeter {
    greeting: string;

    constructor(msg: string) {
        this.greeting = msg;
    }

    greet() {
        return `<h1>${this.greeting}</h1>`;
    }
}

export default Greeter;
```

.babelrc

```
{
  "presets": [
      "airbnb"
  ]
}
```

and i'm trying to run browserify with tsify and babelify:

```
browserify ./script1.ts -o ./app.js -p tsify -t babelify
```

the files get compiled and packaged, but it never runs babelify over the code, I end up with output that still has classes and template strings in it.

if I run babel separately, it works as expected:

```
browserify ./script1.ts -o ./app.js -p tsify
babel ./app.js --out-file ./app-babel.js
```

what step am I missing here?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/40182786/how-to-set-up-grunt-browserify-tsify-babelify check the answer here..maybe this is your issue?

Comment: @suraj gave that a go and it didn't work, unfortunately.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is that babel by default will only operate on `.JS` and `.JSX` files. unfortunately there is currently no way to configure this from a `.babelrc` config file (https://github.com/babel/babel/issues/3741).

So this must be configured from the command line:

`browserify ./script1.ts -o ./app.js -p tsify -t [ babelify --extensions ".ts",".tsx",".js",".jsx" ]`

or from code:

```
browserify({ entries: files })
  .plugin(tsify)
  .transform(babelify, {
    extensions: [
      '.ts', '.tsx', '.js', '.jsx'
    ]
  });
```

Note that babel will still auto load any `.babelrc` content when specifying this extensions list.